# How does Mathematica define an equality ( == ) for Graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am confused. For instance

```
cube = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 6, 6 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 6 <-> 8, 5 <-> 7, 3 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 8 <-> 4, 4 <-> 3};

Graph[cube] == Graph[Sort[cube]]
```

`False`

But they are not two isomorphic graphs only. They are the same graphs, with identical sets of vertices and edges.

Comment: Being equal and being isomorphic are different equivalence relations. `Equal` for `Graph`s might be implemented as `VertexList[g1] == VertexList[g2] && EdgeList[g1] == EdgeList[g2]` (maybe plus further conditions such as `VertexWeights`, `EdgeWeights` etc.) You are probably looking for `IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, g2]`.

Comment: Yes, but two graphs above are equal. I am looking for equality. 
The cube is my examle, because it is easy to permute the vertices so that the permuted graph is isomorphic but not identical.

Comment: It doesn't. `==` is meaningless for graphs. Don't use it.

Comment: Ah. Right. The graphs are equal in a mathematical sense. But if they were equal in the Mathematica sense, they had to produce the same compuational results. But these results depend in the internal odering of graphs, see e.g. `AdjacencyMatrix[g1] == AdjacencyMatrix[g2]`. That's the price to pay if you want to allow arbitrary objects and vertices (and not only natural numbers)

Comment: I added `IGSameGraphQ` to the IGraph/M package precisely for this type of test. It returns `True` if the graphs have the same vertices and same edges, in any order. Properties (such as weights) are ignored.  It returns `True` for your graphs.  Of course you could easily reimplement it.

Comment: What `==` does here is unclear—perhaps it defaults to comparing the input forms with `==`, perhaps something else. I would definitely not rely on it.

Comment: I think we should know that this won't work because we all know how `==` works on lists. Forget that it's a graph, the underlying structure is the list `cube`. We know  `cube==Sort[cube]` returns false, even though they are "the same set" of edges. We can't expect `Graph`-ing both sides to do any better.

Comment: Yeah. I am now aware of the reasons why equality in the computational sense != equality in the mathematical sense, even in functional paradigm